# What are the differences between the difficulty levels in the Campaign and Skirmish modes?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

What are the differences between the Standard, Moderate and Hard difficulty levels in the Campaign mode?

What about between Easiest, Standard, Moderate, Hard, and Hardest in the Standard/Multiplayer Game (Skirmish) mode?

If the AI changes its behavior or strategy depending on the difficulty level, please include that info.

Also, does the AI "cheat" (by giving itself additional resources, etc.)? If yes, what cheats does it do and at what difficulty level(s) does it cheat?

EDIT: In [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87102/4797) to my question below, most of the questions have already been answered. That leaves the question, "*What are the differences between the Standard, Moderate and Hard difficulty levels in the Campaign mode?*" to be answered or expounded upon.

Answer (score 22):

| AI Behavior | EASIEST | EASY | MODERATE | HARD | HARDEST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Advances through the ages | After any human player has advanced to that age | Slowly as a novice player, or as Easiest does | As an experienced player | As fast as possible | As fast as possible; computer players cooperate to slingshot through the ages |
| Attacks First | Never | Never | Occasionally | Yes | Yes |
| Breaks alliances | No | Rarely | Rarely | Yes | Yes |
| Builds a Castle | Rarely | Seldom | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Builds a Wonder | Never | Seldom | If possible | If possible | Seldom |
| Expansion and resource gathering | Slowly selects nearby resources; abandons contested resources | Slowly | Fast | Aggressively defends resources | Aggressively defends resources, destroys enemy resources |
| Monks used to convert buildings | Never | Rarely | Seldom | Yes | Yes |
| Monks used to convert units | Rarely and with very few Monks | Seldom or slowly | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Starting diplomatic stance | Neutral | Neutral | Mix of Neutral and Enemy | Enemy | Enemy |
| Town siege | Never | Seldom | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Walls and towers | Never | Sometimes defensive towers | Yes | Yes | Yes; may build offensive towers |
| Will ally with human players | Yes (unless game would end) | Yes (unless game would end) | With one human only (unless game would end) | Never | No |
| Will ally with humans | Depends on personality | Depends on personality | Sometimes | Never | Never |
| Will ally with other computer Als | No | Yes | Yes | Preferred | Preferred |
| Will trade | Yes | Yes | Sometimes | No | No |
| x - Comments |  |  |  |  | AI is given additional resources at the start of the game |
| Cooperates against human players | No | Sometimes | Sometimes | Yes; coordinated attacks, optimized building strategies. etc. | Yes |

Note: The above is only for random map games.

| Difficulty | Distance an enemy unit must be within when the computer player unit looks for a new target |
| --- | --- |
| easiest | LOS (can be modified by sn-easiest-reaction-percentage) |
| easy | LOS (can be modified by sn-easier-reaction-percentage) |
| moderate | LOS * 2 |
| hard | LOS * 2 |
| hardest | LOS * 2 |

Computer players ignore relics on the easiest level.

| Difficulty | If a non-exploring computer unit gets attacked, the computer player's attack delay is modified |
| --- | --- |
| easiest | allow attacking one minute earlier |
| easy | allow attacking two minutes earlier |
| moderate | allow attacking immediately |
| hard | allow attacking immediately |
| hardest | allow attacking immediately |

| Difficulty | After a wolf kills a unit, have it gorge itself (not attack again) for |
| --- | --- |
| easiest | 35 seconds |
| easy | 30 seconds |
| moderate | 25 seconds |
| hard | 20 seconds |
| hardest | 15 seconds |

| Difficulty | Distance a unit must be within when a wolf looks for a new target |
| --- | --- |
| easiest | LOS * 0.5 |
| easy | LOS * 0.75 |
| moderate | LOS * 2 |
| hard | LOS * 2 |
| hardest | LOS * 2 |

Source: [This Reddit /r/aoe2 post](http://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/xxark/what_are_the_differences_between_the_ai/c5rdahx), which refers to the [Official Computer Player Strategy Builder Guide (cpsb.doc)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100613143616/http://www.cs.uga.edu/%7Epotter/aok/CPSB_AOK2.DOC) in the AOE 2 CD 'GOODIES' folder, pages 63-64. [(Screenshot of the table on page 63)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehBh4.png)

Comment: This is a bit out of date for the Definitive Edition of AoE II. For example, I notice monk unit conversions more frequently on Easiest, as well as the collection of relics (albeit very slowly/minimally). Likewise the "builds a castle" on Easiest should be "never" because they never mine any stone; all games I've played against Easiest AI have 0 stone gathered even if I play for 2 hours against them.

Answer (score 1):

may be it's too late but i think this question "does not take old"...
AOE was criticized for the earliest versions because in the hard/hardest mode it does not take too much to beat the AI, so some cheating was introduced in "Age of the kings"(that's my own opinion).
I can tell that because AI players can upgrade to feudal age since the first 5 mn easily(for any civilization) while human player can not do that with his resources(250 food !)[ less than the required 500 ].to prove that,start a new game ,in hardest mode ,and quit immediately ,then read the screen of the statistics ,you will find out that AI players have well higher scores because they were given more resources ! 
Another thing to mention is that AI managed units/buildings are some how "auto-healing" or "auto-reparing" and more efficient but it's not a bad thing,instead this makes the game more attractive and invites the human intelligence to improve each time and finest the strategy !

Comment: "so some cheating was introduced in "Age of the kings"(that's my own opinion)." - The AI cheated in the same way in the original Age of Empires too.  Hardest mode gave the computer player extra resources.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if it does anything other than improving the AI in the campaign mode.

In skirmish mode it improves the AI, and being attacked by the enemy and how often it happens depends on the difficulty. 
For example; If you play on Easiest in Skirmish mode, the enemy will never attack you, the higher you go in difficulty makes them attack you and more often/earlier in the game.

They don't use "cheats" for resources and you can make them run out of resources just as any other game if you/the game lasts long enough.

Comment: Know the details on how the AI is improved for each different level?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the CPU never cheats, but you have to remember while your human
clicks only control one thing at a time, the CPU is controlling everything
everywhere always.  It might look like auto-repair or auto-heal on
buildings, but the CPU probably takes a villager for a few seconds and
sends them back to work.

One thing I do know, the CPU always knows your location in full even if it 
hasn’t scouted you.  And it will always choose the obnxious option versus
facing you with dignity, especially when it does so at a loss, throwing the
game rather than playing more honorably like not attacking civilians.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Moderate difficulty and above will inherently receive more starting resources than Human player for those three tiers, accordingly. In addition the AI WILL be more prone to earlier aggression regarding resources and other miscellaneous outskirt buildings if importance..

As for strategy, well I merely observed an AI/Computer opponent's play style.. 
-Seemed like the better option is to go for a Villager High by Late Feudal Age rather than Militia/M@A, .. 
-Don't worry about Barracks until Castle Age! Just make sure you have a Dock if practicable, a Blacksmith (and/or a MARKET if allied ASAP for Cartography perk !)
-( Rely on Town Bell if things get ugly before Castle Age..) just build a Castle ASAP when you Advance and gather-point 2 Bombers to an enemy resource ASAP. They won't know what hit em! 
-( (Important) )BEFORE you click Castle Age (III), be sure to have 4-6  villagers mining stone with wheelbarrow + stone mining perk and you should have enough for a Castle as soon as you hit Castle Age.