# What rewards, if any, are there for completing the Age of Empires II: HD Edition campaigns on Hard?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I just completed the first mission of the Joan of Arc campaign on Hard, but after restarting the game, I can't see any sign of the difficulty level at all. Is the difficulty level completed visible anywhere? Does it render some other reward or achievement? I am playing Age of Empires II: The Forgotten, for what it's worth.

I'm not interested in the in-match differences of the difficulty levels, as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77890/what-are-the-differences-between-the-difficulty-levels-in-the-campaign-and-skirm) seems to treat that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty does not offer any reward or give out any different Steam achievements with regards to the campaign.

The only achievements that are difficulty based are in regards to defeating 1 to 7 different computer players (outside of the campaign).  This must be on moderate or higher.

The achievement names are:

1. Humanity Victorious
2. Two Challenging
3. Triumphant Three
4. Four Scored
5. Five Golden Victories
6. Superior Six
7. Seven Sealed Fates

Answer (score 2):

I haven't completed the game's campaign recently, but I believe there is no reward special reward for completing on a harder difficulty.